# Multiple properties on root level when nesting FOR JSON PATH?

Tags: json, sql-server

Running `SQL Server 2016`. Consider the sample below. Nesting `FOR JSON PATH` is easy as long as you give each query an alias. In my case, I want many (but not all) properties to belong to the root - i.e. no alias!

**With unwanted alias `a`:**

```
DECLARE @SomeID int = 1

SELECT
    (SELECT TOP 1 ID, A1, A2 FROM A WHERE ID = @SomeID
        FOR JSON PATH) AS 'a', -- Unwanted!
    (SELECT TOP 1 ID, B1, B2 FROM B WHERE ID = @SomeID
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) AS 'b'
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

If you remove the alias, you get this error when running the query:

> Column expressions and data sources without names or aliases cannot be
>   formatted as JSON text using FOR JSON clause. Add alias to the unnamed
>   column or table.

**No alias. Repetitive queries:**

```
SELECT
    -- Wanted! But tedious for more complex queries...
    (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM A WHERE ID = @SomeID) AS 'id',
    (SELECT TOP 1 A1 FROM A WHERE ID = @SomeID) AS 'a1',
    (SELECT TOP 1 A2 FROM A WHERE ID = @SomeID) AS 'a2',
    (SELECT TOP 1 ID, B1, B2 FROM B WHERE ID = @SomeID
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) AS 'b'
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

The latter produces the right `JSON`. However, in my complex database I cannot repeat the statements like that. Hence, I need a better construct to put many properties on the root - without an alias. **How can this be achieved?**

---

(For completeness. Script to create sample tables below.)

```
CREATE TABLE A(ID int, A1 int, A2 int)
GO

INSERT INTO A(ID, A1, A2)
    SELECT 1, 0, 0
    UNION
    SELECT 1, 1, 1

CREATE TABLE B(ID int, B1 int, B2 int)
GO

INSERT INTO B(ID, B1, B2)
    SELECT 1, 100, 100
    UNION
    SELECT 1, 101, 101
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should produce the JSON you are after, without repeating the queries.

```
select 
top 1
    id, 
    a1, 
    a2,
    (SELECT TOP 1 ID, B1, B2 FROM @B WHERE ID = @SomeID FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) AS 'b'
from a  
where id = @someid
for json path, without_array_wrapper
```

Comment: Thanks! Too obvious :)

Comment: @l33t everything is obvious when you know the answer :)